# computing EP messages in factor graph

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

I'm using infer.net for implementing a dynamic Bayesian network model. every node in each layer is dependent on all nodes in previous layer (we want to train wji, the weights of edges between each node j from the previous level (time t-1) to node i in current level (time t)). node values are shown by yi (value of node i).
The dependency is a complicated function like:
yi(t) = y(t-1).(1-alpha.deltaT) + beta . 1 / (1 + exp(-WeightedSigma))
WeightedSigma = Sigma (Wij * yj(t))
Now I want to put a factor node in my factor graph implementation in infer.NET. I don't know how should I implement such factor node and its message passing. I'm so confused.
Can anyone please help me in this case? 
I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part of this expression that you need a custom factor for is the function
$1/(1+\exp(-Sigma(x)))$.  This is a function from a scalar to a scalar, so should be relatively easy to implement using quadrature.  For examples of this approach, see section 13.8 of [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/) (third edition) or section 1.4 of [EP: A quick reference](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/ep/minka-ep-quickref.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. I'm going to read the documents.

Comment: Dear Tom
How can I define the messages passed from this factor node to each Wij, and to alpha and betas? I don't know how exactly should I define messages: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/docs/How%20to%20add%20a%20new%20factor%20and%20message%20operators.aspx Like in this link how they are computed after we have the distribution after removing data i (\i)? Thanks a lot

Comment: The other thing is that, I have these different variables (there are two matrices W1 and W2 which are used in this Wij*Yj term) to which I have to send messages from my factor node. 
As I explained before I have 1 / (1 + exp(-WeightedSigma)){ in the formula: WeightedSigma = Sum (Wij * yj(t)) }
Now I don't understand how to propagate these messages back to these W's (elements of W1 and W2).

Comment: Messages to W, alpha, and beta are handled by the product factor.  Take a look at the [TrueSkill](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67956) paper for an example of how message passing gets broken down across different factors.